# Connecting query to database in Visual Studio error

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, web, database-connection

Hope you all are doing good. I tried to find an exact error like mine, I couldn't find any concrete solution that worked. So thought about asking a new one.

Just started learning ASP.net using c# and I cannot seem to get past this issue.
I did some basic coding and got stuck at the part where i tried to work along with databases.

Tried this code:
https://gyazo.com/1f42d255dd435a35ecee3b838724d95d

Debug suggestion:
https://gyazo.com/2f711822f37a986ba4d6d8337159f63f

DB:
https://gyazo.com/c8f17068bdc4f499f98b3b0fb6706af9

ERROR:
https://gyazo.com/142578bba8bc24fc17d2732a777c2b1d

Code:

```
 protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   // string abra = "data source = .; database = Practise ;integrated security=SSPI";
    SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("Data source =.; database = Practise ; user id=sa ;password=souparnika");
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select * from Credentials",con);
    con.Open();
    GridView1.DataSource = cmd.ExecuteReader();
    GridView1.DataBind();
    con.Close();
}
```

It throws an error at con.Open();  every time. Tried stepping over(debug if that's the actual term) and found that the "Server was not found/ connection could not be established" pop up.

In data source I also tried:

1. .
2. .\SQLEXPRESS
3. SQLEXPRESS
4. (local)
5. (local)\SQLEXPRESS
6. DESKTOP-HKNGLGB\SQLEXPRESS

In example 3,5 and 6, it does not accept the "\" character and throws an error.

Any kind of help will be greatly appreciated.

P.S: Also tried Windows Authentication.Database and table names are correct.

Comment: Please put all code and any database samples *in the question* (images are terrible to read, and don't allow cut and paste to test a solution). Also if there is an error *tell us what it is* including type of any exception and its message as text in the question.

Comment: Added the code, I do not know how to send you the .mdf files, sorry!

Comment: Added error screenshot too!

Comment: `Data Source=DESKTOP-HKNGLGB\\SQLEXPRESS;`

Comment: Really it opens just fine then throws an error on close?

Comment: @Squirrel Worked like charm mate! Thank you!

Comment: @Paparazzi It used to open up with that error!

Comment: Not buying it gets past the open() and fails on the close() ever.

Comment: @Paparazzi I meant that it throws the error while trying to connect to server itself. During the execution of con.Open(); (I've attached the error page and debug)

Comment: I'll try again s l o w.  "It throws an error at con.Close(); every time."

Comment: @Paparazzi Oops, my bad. Was meant to be con.Open() . Apologies!
 (Edited the question, thank you :) )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually it throws the error on `con.Open();` since it is unable to connect to the server.

> it does not accept the "\" character and throws an error

Backslash `\` is a special character that needs to be escaped when it is used in literals. As @Squirrel wrote, it can be escaped by another `\`. So you need to change your connection string in c# code to:

```
Data source=DESKTOP-HKNGLGB\\SQLEXPRESS;database=Practise;user id=sa;password=souparnika
```

Comment: You sir are genius. This worked like magic! Thank you very much sir! Have a great day!